Specify binary source for iOS and tvOS in Podspec file
I have XCFramework which i distribute via SPM and Cocoapods.
For the source I pass a link where the zipped binary can be downloaded from.
For example in Package.swift I can kinda check for what kind of platform it will be used:
let tvOSPlatform: Bool
#if os(tvOS)
tvOSPlatform = true
#else
tvOSPlatform = false
#endif

let package = Package(
    name: "MySDK",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
        .tvOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
         .library(name: "MySDK", targets: ["MySDK"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
          .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.22.1"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "MySDK",
            url: tvOSPlatform ? "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_tvOS_URL}" : "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_iOS_URL}",
            checksum: tvOSPlatform ? "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_tvOS_SHA256}" : "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_iOS_SHA256}"
         )
    ]
)

This approach with boolean flag doesnt seem great, but at least Package.swift passes linting and maybe it will work, I haven't tested yet.
Though, I have another issue with the same logic but for distribution via cocoapods in podspec file. In the code snippet below is something what I ideally would like to achieve:
if spec.platform.name == :tvos
    spec.source = { :http => "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_tvOS_URL}", :sha256 => "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_tvOS_SHA256}" }
else
    spec.source = { :http => "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_iOS_URL}", :sha256 => "${ARTIFACTORY_STAGE_iOS_SHA256}" }
end

Basically, I need a way to determine when I would use ios artifact or tvos.
Any other ideas of how to distribute a binary for different platforms are welcome! Thank you.
